# VB 6.0 ActiveX control exception handling and cleanup

Tags: memory-management, exception, user-controls, vb6, activex

I have created various activex controls in a single ".ocx" file using VB 6.0.

I am using these user controls in my MFC application. I have added these controls in my MFC PropertyPage dialog in design time. This propertypages are added into Propertysheet, This propertyPage is added into a ActiveX container control. Finally the container control will be loaded by another application.

My dialogs are getting loaded properly in Windows XP, Windows 7 32 Bit operating system.
In Windows 2008 server and Windows 7 64 bit operating systems, when my VB 6.0 usercontrols added in property page, then `CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog getting failed (throws exception)`. I have tried possible MFC exceptions to catch the exception, But the default (...) catch block only getting executed.

When I remove the VB 6.0 user controls from PropertyPage then there is no exception.

1. How to handle the exception thrown by VB 6.0 User controls?
2. How to make sure the memory created in VB 6.0 user control has been freed up properly?

Comment: Document the specific exception you see.  Be sure to use the proper version of regsrv32.exe on a 64-bit version of Windows.  You need the one in c:\windows\syswow64 to get a 32-bit registration.

Comment: I couldn't get the proper exception. instead my default catch block is getting executed catch(...)  {  }

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out all the code in the VB6 controls project, and then recompiling. Retry using the property pages. If you don't get the same problem, then you are in luck. Uncomment the code method by method, until you find the malfunctioning code.

Comment: Thanks mark. I have already added exception handling in almost all the methods in VB 6.0 control class but exception is not captured in VB. I will try commenting methods one by one.

Comment: I have an new ActiveX Control with no source code.This also have same issue.

Comment: Note: One new abservation is whenever the VB Controls added in PropertyPage (which is added with in PropertySheet) the issue occurs. When I tried to add the VB ACtiveX Controls into VC ActiveX Container,it works fine.

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - I wonder whether there is some dependency which the ActiveX Container is loading, but your DLL isn't. It would just take one failing LoadLibrary() and you would be dereferencing a null pointer. Have a look at what DLLs and OCXs are loaded into the process, and see whether there is something obviously missing from your MFC application.

Comment: In both cases My ActiveX Container is loaded. ie., In first case : VB Controls are added into propertyPage and PropertyPage is added in propertysheet and PropertySheet is added in top of ActiveXContainer, I opened ActiveX Container.  In second case : VB Controls are directly added in ActiveX Container and I am opening ActiveX Container.